# Export multiple tables to Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, export

I can not export multiple tables of the same web page to excel.

One table to one file works - there are lots of jquery plugin that can handle that.

But a table per worksheet I can not find.

Here is an example of my tables

```
 <body>
<table id ="table1">
     <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>N°</th>
      <th>titre1</th>
      <th>titre2</th>
      <th>titre3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    <table id ="table2">
     <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>N°</th>
      <th>titre1</th>
      <th>titre2</th>
      <th>titre3</th>
      <th>titre4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>val4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button>Export</button>
```

Comment: Bonjour, but i dont know spanish

Comment: *S'il vous plaît poster en anglais*. Please post your Question in english

Comment: @SM Ahmed, I don't either, but I think its French.

Comment: Isn't this French? :D Anyway, please do only use English language on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Phoenix gracious, my bad

Comment: @ Well-meaning translators: We **don't** translate questions on SO, either via machine translation or because you speak the language. The OP needs to be able to read and respond to comments and answers, and so they need English resources at *their* end to help them. (Or, of course, [Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/).)

Comment: SO users showing maturity by not downvoting becuase the original post isn't in English. :)

Comment: T.J: So perhaps we can give this new visitor to SO that information before downvoting to hell and closing?